# Dispatch same compute shader multiple times

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible and safe to call `glDispatchCompute()` for same compute shader multiple times or I have to always wait untill the shader finishes and then dispatch again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as there is no memory dependency between the two dispatch operations (ie: you're not accessing data written by a previous dispatch), it should be fine. Otherwise, you will need to invoke `glMemoryBarrier`, with bits appropriate to the way the next dispatch will access the data.

Changes to actual uniform variables (through `glUniform` or `glProgramUniform`) between the two dispatches are fine. Changes to UBO data is fine *so long as* you're modifying the buffer's data through actual API calls (`glBufferSubData` or call `glMapBufferRange` between the dispatches). If you're modifying the buffer's data through a pointer to persistently mapped buffer data, then you need to do a full CPU/GPU sync before you can modify any bytes that were being read by the previous dispatch calls.

Comment: I forgot to ask one more thing in my question. Let's say that compute shader still runs and I set uniform(for another dispatch), does it mean that the previous dispatch might take the new uniform or the data are stored somewhere for each dispatch? Anyway thanks for answer

Comment: @MichaeltLoL: If you're talking about an actual `glProgramUniform` call, then it's fine. If you're talking about updating a UBO, then that's fine too *as long as* you're not doing it via modifying the memory through a persistent mapped buffer pointer (that is, you're executing a non-unsychronized `glMapBufferRange` call between the two dispatches, or invoking `glBufferSubData`).

Comment: yes I was talking about `glProgramUniform` thank you!